# Accessing file system in an iOS device

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm an absolute newbie to Xamarin world. I'm working on a web application where a user completes a long form (say some 100+ fields) and then submits the form which will write the information to a database. One of the requirement is user should be able to load the form, resume his work even when he is Offline( No internet connection). I have used HTML5 Application cache, Local Storage in Html5, KnockOut.JS, Java script so that for every 2 seconds all the user form information is saved to Local Storage of the browser. But lately, I noticed with few users that the forms are getting deleted sometimes due to an iOS update. Also I don't want to rely on browsers cookie/cache to store this information.

I want to find out what my options are with Xamarin. Can I use a component like 'UIWebview' in the Xamarin app to launch my web application and then access the file system of iOS of that Xamarin app from the browser launched ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can!

One launch image plus one screen with `UIWebView` is what you need for your task. You can handle `UIWebView`'s event to save and load it's state.

Good news is that such app could be small enought to build it using free ([Starter](https://store.xamarin.com/)) version of platform.

Comment: Thanks for the input Maxim. So, can I save the information on the device ? I will go ahead and start with building the app.

Comment: Sure you can. Xamarin provides (almost) the same platform features as Apple.